# rename (or alias) the "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service to "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am playing with Symfony3.3 and I've received this message:

"Autowiring services based on the types they implement is deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and won't be supported in version 4.0. You should rename (or alias) the "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" service to "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" instead."

I've added app/config/legacy_aliases.yml with the alias

```
services:
doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager: "@Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"
```

but I still receive the same error message:

[image]

Any suggestion about how to remove this deprecation?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add

```
Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager:
    alias: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
    public: false
```

inside my `app/config/services.yml`.

There was no need to add a `legacy_aliases` file.